# Change props of Component without re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to change the props of a Component without a re-render. In react native I need to change the `scrollEnabled` prop of scrollview without re-rendering the whole UI.

Would this be possible by going really deep down the Component API or something and changing that prop without a whole re-render?

Edit:

I don’t need something like useMemo or useRef. It’s really about changing the props of the the `ScrollView` without re-rendering anything but that component. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't get the new value of state or prop without rerendering the component.**

But you can prevent rerendering of those components, that don't require those props.

You can use `React.memo`. It prevents renendering of the component, if its props don't change. Be careful how you handle objects, arrays, functions... because they get new reference on each render.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `useRef`

> useRef is a React Hook that lets you reference a value that’s not needed for rendering.

https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.memo` with a custom comparison function. https://react.dev/reference/react/memo